# consistent spaces and alignment between textboxes and labels

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, controls

I am designing a **win form** using **C#** having around 100 textboxes and labels. It is very tedious task to make the spaces between the textboxes, labels consistent and also the alignments of the controls manually.

Is there any way I can specify the space between the controls so that every controls of the form have the space between them. And also the alignments of the controls.

Comment: Use `TableLayoutPanel`.

Comment: In addition to TFP you may think about UserCOntrols, that is if all or most of your textboxes and labels are grouped together. And of course you can always generate them in code..

Answer (score 1):

Use `TableLayoutPanel` and set your `Dock` property accordingly for controls.

You can read more details from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

For consistent spaces and alignments you can also use **Format** option from Visual Studio Menu bar when you are on designer page.You can make same size,align and set hor-ver spacing there. (Select the controls you want to align or set spacing)